We getting different scale of dxf to base DWG file once we did georeferenced in QGIS?
We getting different scale of dxf to base DWG file once we did georeferenced in QGIS ?

Maybe the reason for your issue is that the GDAL DXF driver is setting the unit into Imperial Inches https://gdal.org/en/release-3.10/drivers/vector/dxf.html#units

GDAL writes DXF files with measurement units set to "Imperial -
Inches". If you need to change the units, edit the $MEASUREMENT and
$INSUNITS variables in the header template.

In the GDAL version 3.11 this behavior will change.

INSUNITS=[AUTO​/​HEADER_VALUE​/​UNITLESS​/​INCHES​/​FEET​/​MILLIMETERS​/​CENTIMETERS​/​METERS​/​US_SURVEY_FEET]:
(GDAL >= 3.11) Defaults to AUTO. Drawing units for the model space
($INSUNITS system variable). The default AUTO mode first check if the
written layer has a projected CRS, and if so uses is linear units to
determine the value of $INSUNITS. Otherwise it fallbacks to the value
of the header template (HEADER_VALUE mode), which is INCHES.

